# How can I get with port server is listen based on the PID of the server?

Tags: c, sockets, server, client

How can I get with port server is listen based on the PID of the server?

I want to connect to a server as a client in c (using ubuntu).
and I'm trying to do that only based on the process id of the server.

Comment: if you know the pid of the server then you are most likely already connected to the server. You can use netstat at server to get the port process is listening at - **sudo netstat -ntlp | grep $pid/**

Comment: btw, it would be nice of you to go through the answers to your own questions and mark good answers as accepted. You are asking the questions. You are thanking the person who made good answer but do not accept theirs answers. It causes other people to try to resolve your questions because they looks like unresolved. Does it make sense to you?